Use "this" inside class for conditional typing
I would like to know if it is possible to use "this" keyword inside a class for conditional typing of some field of that same class.
When I tried this:
export class BfpComponent {
    @Input() public ids?: this['multiple'] extends true ? string [] : string;

    @Input({ transform: booleanAttribute }) public multiple: boolean;
}

the compiler always defaults to string, so the condition is always false.

How could it know at compile time what this.multiple is? Isn't it easier to always take an array?

I don't really know, that's the reason I asked the question.
That does indeed work, I was just wondering about this question because it simplifies the cases where I want to reuse a component and don't want to make its usage too verbose, for example on two-way binding in Angular.

If it could be a string or string[], callers would always have to check obj.multiple before setting it, seems like extra work.

no, because multiple is always set at the beginning and not changed again, and value passed is string when multiple = false and string[] when multiple = true. So that check is not necessary on the caller side.

There's no way for the compiler to know it will never be changed. It could if you create a base class and use type narrowing by hardcoding the multiple to false and true in each subclass.

Please see an example at this Playground Link Not sure if it can be adapted to your needs since you don't want two classes but you may be able to.
